# PDFBox - options to increase the performance

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have 2 questions regarding PDFBox library (JAVA):

1. I have just started using PDFBox library and though it's working well, I couldn't
   help noticing that it runs slower than ITEXT (the other pdf library I used) when
   using `ut.mergeDocuments()` method (against concat_pdf.main(..) of ITEXT).
   Does any one know if/how I can increase the performance of this tool?
2. I see that PDFBox is more sensitive to encrypted files. The ITEXT is allowing 
   me to do merge on encrypted PDF's but PDFBox is throwing an exception stating:

   > "PDFBoxConcat failedjava.io.IOException: Error: destination PDF is encrypted, can't append encrypted PDF documents."

Does any one know how come it works on ITEXT but not on PDFBox?
My guess is that the ITEXT is more sophisticated to know exactly what is encrypted
and allowing actions by that, while the PDFBox is just checking if it's encrypted or not.

Can anyone confirm this for me?

I have this code (open source) of pfdBox for the `mergeDocuments()` method where you can see the check for encryption:

```
 if( destination.isEncrypted() )
        {
            throw new IOException( "Error: destination PDF is encrypted, can't append encrypted PDF documents." );
        }
```

I tried to put this on remark but the merged document came out as gibberish.

---

Just adding some code examples of my attempts to improve performance.

These are the 3 different ways I tried to do this:

```
private static void PDFBoxConcat(String filePath) {

    PDFMergerUtility ut = new PDFMergerUtility();

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        ut.addSource(filePath);
    }
    ut.setDestinationFileName("C:\\amdocs\\sensis\\dlv858\\pdfBox" + testNum + ".pdf");         
    try {
        ut.mergeDocuments();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("PDFBoxConcat failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private static void PDFBoxConcat2(String filePath) {


    String [] fileNamesArray = new String[51];
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        fileNamesArray[i] = filePath;
    }
    fileNamesArray[i] = "C:\\amdocs\\sensis\\dlv858\\pdfM" + testNum + ".pdf";
    try {
        PDFMerger.main(fileNamesArray);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void PDFBoxConcat3(String filePath) {

    ArrayList<InputStream> list = new ArrayList<InputStream>(); 
    PDFMergerUtility ut = new PDFMergerUtility();

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++){

        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        list.add(inputStream);
    }

    ut.addSources(list);

    try {
        ut.mergeDocuments();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("PDFBoxConcat failed");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you forgot to to login when asking the question?

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your first question: Does any one know if/how I can increase the performance of this tool(= Apache PdfMergerUtility)?

The following setting helped me to reduce the merge time by ~ 75%:

```
pdfMergerUtility.setDocumentMergeMode(PDFMergerUtility.DocumentMergeMode.OPTIMIZE_RESOURCES_MODE);
```